# c# wpf textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I need to give space between letter of text-block as 34.

 text-Block has property with Font-Stretch property 
but it has its own (Ultraexpanded,condensed, ....such and such)

```
       <Style x:Key="diningcode" TargetType="TextBlock">


            <Setter Property="FontStretch" Value="UltraExpanded"/>

        </Style>
```

I want to change this 'ultraExpanded' property to 34
any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this :

```
public class AdvancedStretchTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines charachter/letter spacing
    /// </summary>
    public int Tracking
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(TrackingProperty);
        set => SetValue(TrackingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tracking", typeof(int), typeof(AdvancedStretchTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(0,
                TrackingPropertyChanged));

    static void TrackingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(o is AdvancedStretchTextBlock tb) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            return;

        tb._tracking.X = (int)e.NewValue;
        tb._trackingAlignment.X = -(int)e.NewValue * tb.Text.Length;

        if (tb._lastTrackingTextLength == tb.Text.Length)
            return; // Avoid re-creating effects when you don't have to..

        // Remove unused effects (string has shortened)
        while (tb._trackingEffects.Count > tb.Text.Length)
        {
            tb.TextEffects.Remove(tb._trackingEffects[tb._trackingEffects.Count - 1]);
            tb._trackingEffects.RemoveAt(tb._trackingEffects.Count - 1);
        }

        tb._lastTrackingTextLength = tb.Text.Length;

        // Add missing effects (string has grown)
        for (int i = tb._trackingEffects.Count; i < tb.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            var fx = new TextEffect()
            {
                PositionCount = i,
                Transform = tb._tracking
            };
            tb._trackingEffects.Add(fx);
            tb.TextEffects.Add(fx);
        }

        // Ugly hack to fix overall alignment
        tb.RenderTransform = tb._trackingAlignment;

    }

    private readonly TranslateTransform _tracking = new TranslateTransform();
    private readonly TranslateTransform _trackingAlignment = new TranslateTransform();
    private readonly List<TextEffect> _trackingEffects = new List<TextEffect>();
    int _lastTrackingTextLength;

}
```

And for the xaml use :

```
<local:AdvancedStretchTextBlock Text=""... Tracking="-10"/>
```

ref : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/789c3e1b-e3ae-476f-b37f-d93ef6d0cb7b/character-spacing-in-textblocktextelement?forum=wpf

Comment: Thx, seemed like it working. actually I tried to create the class CondensedTextBlock : TextBlock but it does not worked inside of the canvas. but your 'AdvancedStretchTextBlock ' work fine in canvas. what make it work fine in canvas ?

Comment: if I want to understand your code  any resource or tutorial u suggest?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-apply-transforms-to-text

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753318(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try it out yourself to find out the answer, but obviously you cannot assess `-10` to `FontStretch` property as the property only accept a collection of options as input value. 
The option you're looking for may be `FontStretches.ExtraCondensed`. I suggest you go to MSDN to read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontstretches.extracondensed(v=vs.110).aspx